# How can I save ALL of my Outlook 2010 configuration settings?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

I would like to backup all of my Outlook 2010 settings, including:

1. Signatures
2. View configurations
3. Font settings
4. Any/all settings available under "Options"
5. And so on...

What files, directories and registry keys must be backed up to capture all this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path for each file/folder that needs to be backed up is mentioned below:

- Personal Folders file (.pst): 
  `%userprofile%\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Outlook Data file (.ost): `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Personal Address Book (.pab): `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Offline Address Book (.oab): `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Navigation Panel settings (.xml): `%appdata%\Outlook\profile name.xml`.
- Registered Microsoft Exchange extensions (.dat): `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Rules (.rwz): `%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Print styles (Outlprnt with no extension): `%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Signatures (.rtf, .txt, .htm): `%appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures`.
- Stationery (.htm): `%commonprogramfiles%\Microsoft Shared\Stationery`.
- Custom forms:
  `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Forms`.
- Dictionary (.dic): `%appdata%\Microsoft\UProof`.
- Templates (.oft): `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`.
- Send/Receive settings (.srs): `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- Message (.msg, .htm, .rtf): `%userprofile%\Documents`.

Or use tool for automate this process, for example [ABF Outlook backup](http://www.abf-soft.com/outlook-backup.shtml).

[image]

Comment: In which of the above areas is information about emails that you mark "not as junk" stored?